# Can not get discord bot to work, getting a Supplied roles is not a role

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Was trying to get this discord bot i found on github to work, but I keep getting a TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied roles is not a Role, Snowflake or Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes.            at GuildMemberRoleManager.add (C:\Users\chris\Desktop\DonnieThornberryBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildMemberRoleManager.js:93:15) Error. Code below

```
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ ws: { intents: ['GUILDS', 'GUILD_MESSAGES', 'GUILD_PRESENCES', 'GUILD_VOICE_STATES'] } });
const {
    prefix,
    token
} = require("./config.json");

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('guildCreate', (guild) => {
  console.log(`Creating role in` + guild.name);
  guild.roles.create({
    data: {
      name: 'Donnies Target',
    },
  })
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
});

client.on('message', async (msg) => {
    let guildName = msg.guild.name;
    const args = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === "join" && msg.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_CHANNELS")) {
    console.log("Command for " + command + " Recieved in Server: " + guildName);
        if (!msg.member.voice.channel) {
            return msg.reply("You're not in any voice channel");
        }
        await msg.member.voice.channel.join();
  }
  if (command === "leave" && msg.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_CHANNELS")) {
    console.log("Command for " + command + " Recieved in Server: " + guildName);
        if (!msg.member.voice.channel) {
            return msg.reply("You're not in any voice channel");
        }
        await msg.member.voice.channel.leave();
  }
  if (command === "mark" && msg.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_CHANNELS"))
  {
        if (!msg.mentions.users.size) {
      return msg.reply('You need to tag a user in order to mark them!');
    }
    let markedUser = msg.mentions.members.first();
    let role = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Donnies Target");
        markedUser.roles.add(role)

        return msg.channel.send(`${markedUser} has been marked!`);      
  }
  if (command === "unmark" && msg.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_CHANNELS"))
  {
      if(!args.length)
        return msg.channel.send(`Please tag a user!`);
        let unmarkUser = msg.mentions.members.first();
        let role = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Donnies Target");
        unmarkUser.roles.remove(role)
      msg.channel.send(`${unmarkUser} has been unmarked`);
  }
  if(command === "help" && msg.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_CHANNELS") )
  {
    const helpEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("#0099ff")
            .setTitle("Donnie Thornberry")
            .setAuthor(
                "Bot by shaftAndi#5802",
                "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/571412838388727809/532a483b9c1fc768d1d5a1d4b0c9d4ee.webp?size=128"
            )
            .setDescription(
                "Donnie Thornberry will interrupt your friends in voice!"
            )
            .addFields(
                { 
                    name: "- !d join", 
                    value: "Joins the voice channel you are in" 
                },
                { 
                    name: "- !d leave", 
                    value: "Leaves the voice channel incase needed!" 
                },
                {
                    name: "- !d mark <tag user>",
                    value: "Targets a user with a role!."
                },
        {
                    name: "- !d unmark <tag user>",
                    value: "Removes targeted role from user!."
                }
            );
        return msg.channel.send(helpEmbed);
  }
});

client.on('guildMemberSpeaking', async (member, speaking) => {
  if(member.roles.cache.some((role) => role.name === "Donnies Target"))
  {
    const connection = await member.voice.channel.join();
    const dispatcher = connection.play("./donnie2.mp3")
    dispatcher.pause();
    if(speaking)
    {
        console.log("Spoken!")
        dispatcher.resume();
    }
    if(speaking == false)
    {
        console.log("Silent!")
        dispatcher.pause();
    }
  }    
  });

client.login(token);
```

Comment: I suggest you ask whomever created this discord bot in the issues of his repository.

Comment: See I would but it seems they are not active

Comment: In the server your bot is in, is there a role named "Donnies Target"? If there isn't, then it is trying to add `undefined`, causing the error

Comment: there is a role called that

Comment: To confirm, this error happens when you use the "mark" command, right?

Comment: yes after i do the mark command , i will get the message "user has been marked in the discord chat, but this error comes up in the cmd line"

Answer (score 0):

When you added the role to the marked user:

```js
let markedUser = msg.mentions.members.first();
let role = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Donnies Target");
markedUser.roles.add(role)
```

You have to put the ID and not the role object itself, so you need to change

```js
markedUser.roles.add(role)
```

to

```js
markedUser.roles.add(role.id)
```

Double-check the rest of the code it must be the same way of adding roles.

Comment: Question when changing that it says that id is undefined so would i need to define ID to Donnies Target

Comment: @Christopher Hey so you can define the role as 
`msg.guild.roles.cache.get('put the role id here')`
after that, you can just add it normally I guess, but if you are using v13 make sure u got intents!!